# JavaScript array to number

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you explain why ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] = 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10)

I'm wondering something for few days...I know that unary plus in JavaScript first converts it's operand to Number. I'm applying + to an empty array and I get the following result:

```
+[] == 0
```

When I do this:

```
+[1] == 1
```

But:

```
+[1,2] == NaN
```

The last two things are almost clear but why the empty array is 0?!
Is this connected with:

```
[] == false
```

Some times ECMAScript makes me wonder a lot...

```
alert([![]+[]][+[]][+[]]+[![]+[]][+[]][+!+[]]+[!+[]+[]][+![]][+![]]+[![]+[]][+[]][+!+[]]+[![]+[]][+[]][+!+[]+!+[]]+' '+(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]);
```

Best regards!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10/7202287#7202287 at the end I posted an explanation for `+[] === 0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stringified form of the empty `Array` is an empty string:

```
> [].toString()
""
```

The unary operator `+` converts to `Number` objects, so, it converts an empty string to `0`:

```
> Number("")
0
```

This explains why `+[] == 0` is true.