# Why is the result of adding two empty arrays in JavaScript a string?

Tags: javascript

Adding two empty arrays:

```
[] + []
```

results in an empty string. Why?

Comment: There's a screencast from a recent conference session that explores odd behaviors of Ruby and Javascript, but as I understand it the Javascript idiosyncrasies are implementation-specific.

Comment: I once wrote this part of a larger answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10/7202287#7202287).

Comment: @BrianDriscoll that's actually why I am asking the question.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: I'm assuming you mean [wat](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Comment: @Rocket yes, I just couldn't readily find the URL.

Comment: To add two arrays together, use concat().  `array1.concat(array2)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `+` operator only exists for numbers and strings. When you use it on another type, JavaScript tries to convert the type (first to string, then int).

When arrays are casts to strings, they are output as comma-separated strings.

So, `[] + []` => `"" + ""` => `""`.

Another example:  `[1,2] + [3,4]` => `"1,2" + "3,4"` => `"1,23,4"`

**Relevant Spec:** https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus

Answer (score 4):

In JavaScript, there are two types of value: primitives which include `null`, `undefined`, `boolean`, `string` and `number`; everything else is an `object`, including `array`

*When adding things, JavaScript converts values to numbers, strings or primitives.* Internally, JavaScript uses the `toPrimitive` method to convert variables to primitive.

Here is the signature of `toPrimitive`:

```
toPrimitive(input, preferedType);
```

With `[] + []`, JavaScript converts `[]` to a primitive, first tries `valueOf()` which returns the array:

```
var arr = [];
arr.valueOf() === arr // true
```

As that result is not a primitive, `toString()` is called and returns the empty string (string is a primitive). Therefore, the result of `[] + []` is the concatenation of two empty strings.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `+` operator serializes the two arrays and concatenates the two results. The serialization is done via the `Array.prototype.toString` method which basically does this:

```
function () { return this.join(','); }
```

The two arrays are empty, thus the string returned by `toString` is also empty and two empty strings make an empty string as well.

Answer (score 0):

Speculation, but I'm guessing that JavaScript is attempting concatenation there, rather than additon.

Answer (score 0):

The + operator will try to convert the array to string. Use the concat command, if you want to join two or more arrays.