# Why does _=$=+[],++_+''+$ evaluate to 10

Tags: javascript

I saw `_=$=+[],++_+''+$` that evaluates to `10` in this question [Why does ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] return the string "10"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10). ( http://jsfiddle.net/tVMqM/ ).

Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: Honestly these exercises are only valuable if you figure them out yourself. Take the expression apart piece by piece; draw a syntax diagram.

Comment: Doesn't the answer to the question you posted explain it?

Comment: The link you provided already includes an in-depth answer to your question. See the post by 'pimvdb' at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10

Comment: I think you'll find a lot of answers in the post you linked. Basically, its string concatenation of `1` and `0` making `10`.

Comment: `-~[]+[~~[]]` also equals to 10 ;)

Comment: Glad this was closed. StackOverflow could be flooded with an endless combination of expressions evaluating to some magic result. These have no usefulness in the real world, and as @Pointy stated, are only really valuable if you work them out yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resolves to 1 (true) `_=$=+[],++_`

Converts it to a string `+''`

Adds 0 to string `+$`

**Edit: More detail for first part...**

Create variables _ and $ `_=$=`

Set variables equal to 0 `+[]`

Increment _ variable `++_`

Comment: okay, but why `+$`==0 and why `_=$=+[],++_`==1

Comment: `Resolves to 1 (true) _=$=+[],++_`; can you explain a bit further as to why?

Comment: I've edited my response to include more detail for the first part.

Comment: *"Set variables equal to empty set"* should be: *"Set variables equal to 0"*

Answer (score 4):

There's a pretty good explanation [here](http://adamcecc.blogspot.com/2011/01/javascript.html).  HackerNews has some great discussion on the topic [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2129745).

It's important to note that this isn't the integer 10, but rather the string "10".