# How "NaNundefined"[10] ="e" Or ([+[][[]]]+[][[]])[++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]] = "e"?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you explain why ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] = 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10)

As we all know that Cheat sheets are the shortest ways we can find to accomplish things
by using the charsets. I cant uderstand how it is getting executed. Can any one clarify?

How `"NaNundefined"[10] ="e"`  Or `([+[][[]]]+[][[]])[++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]] = "e"` ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you are asking here...

Comment: `"NaNundefined"[10]` refers to the 11th character of that string which is `"e"`. `([+[][[]]]+[][[]])` is just an obfuscated way of producing `"NaNundefined"` and `++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]` the same for producing `10`. But I 'm not sure what the purpose of the question is.

Answer (score 5):

`"NaNundefined"[10] ="e"` is easy - `e` is the eleventh char in the string.

`([+[][[]]]+[][[]])[++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]] = "e"` is a bit harder, but you can easily just split it up:

```
[+[][[]]] -> [ NaN ]
[][[]] -> undefined
[ NaN ] + undefined -> "NaNundefined"
++[[]][+[]] -> 1
[+[]] -> "0"
1 + "0" -> "10"
"NaNundefined"["10"] -> "e"
```

The second version is effectively a way to construct the first, (ab)using the weak typing of javascript operators (for example, `[NaN] + "" -> "NaN"`). It also uses the fact that arrays in javascript are always indexed by a string (so `array[10]` is equivalent to `array["10"]`).

The second version could be seen as a obfuscation, if you want to prevent someone to understand the code. It doesn't really serve much of a purpose though, at least in everyday coding life.

Answer (score 0):

The character at index 10 is an e:
`"NaNundefin`**e**`d"[10] ="e"`

Comment: It is the second `e` in the string