# How navigator read atomic javascript?

Tags: javascript

I found something who disturbed me.

How can a navigator can interpret this kind of code :

```
[][(![]+[])[+[[+[]]]]+([][[]]+[])[+[[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]]]+
```

as javascript ??

Here is a fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/6Cr4H/

Does every languages have an atomic form like this ??

Comment: Is that a practical question or a game ? There are many examples of such games.

Comment: thats most likely obfuscated code ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29 ) and done because guys like you wanna look into the code... and the autor wants to keep it a secret as much as possible ( but yes, there are ways to get behind that ) or simply a self developed parser in that javascript

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks to interpret one specific example of a golfed code.


Comment: ( look my rep, i'm a newbie, it's a real question for me )

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/can-you-explain-why-10)

Comment: And many more: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+%22![]%22

Comment: thanks a lot for your links. I've learned something today with your answers.

Comment: Yes, it's good to know how that works, because even when you don't obfuscate code you probably use casts a lot in JS and this is mostly about the strange rules of casting.