# Can you explain object and array arithmetic in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why these operations yield these results:

(I understand the first one is somehow related to strings being based on arrays but what does 'based on' mean here, how does it work internally)

```
[] + [] = ""

[] - []= 0

[] + {} = "[object Object]"

[] - {} = NaN

{} + {} = NaN

{} - {} = NaN

{} + 1 = 1
```

Comment: The accepted answer to [Why is ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] = "10"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-is-10) explains this really well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the `+` operator javascript will attempt to convert the elements being added together first into a string, then into an int. When you cast an empty array to a string you get `""` therefore `"" + "" = ""`

```
[] + [] = ""  // equates to "" + "" = ""
```

When using the `-` operator javascript will attempt to convert the element into integers. Empty arrays cast into integers will product `0` so `0 - 0 = 0`

```
[] - []= 0 // equates to 0 - 0 = 0
```

Same thing here, the empty array is being converted to `""` and the object is being converted to  `"[object Object]"` because of the concatenation with the empty string the result is `"" + "[object Object]" = "[object Object]"`

```
[] + {} = "[object Object]" // equates to "" + "[object Object]" = "[object Object]"
```

`{}` cannot be cast to an int so is instead cast to `undefined` and `0 - undefined = NaN`

```
[] - {} = NaN // equates to 0 - undefined = NaN
```

When an expressions starts with an empty object literal javaScript interprets the first {} as an empty code block and ignores it so evaluates the following expressions as `+ {}` which is `NaN`

```
{} + {} = NaN // equates to + {} = NaN


{} - {} = NaN // equates to - {} = NaN


{} + 1 = 1 // equates to + 1 = 1
```

Comment: `- {}` results in `NaN` not `undefined`.

Comment: You are right, the `{}` is undefined so it is the same as writing `- undefined` which is `NaN`

Comment: But how can an object be `undefined`? `Number({})` also returns `NaN`.

Comment: javascript has some weirdness when you create objects without storing them into a value. For instance, try this in your console: `{}` and `{foo: "bar", baz: "qux"}`. The first one will output "undefined" the second will throw an error unless you store it to a variable. When the javascript engine encounters an object literal on the left side of an expression it ignores it as an empty code block