# Javascript ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] === "10"

Tags: javascript

this is not a totally serious question, but I think it might help me to understand another aspect of Javascript maybe.

Some time ago, I found this strange code:

```
<script>
if( ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] === "10" )
    alert( ':o');
</script>
```

It's actually `true`!

Does anyone of you know why?

Comment: I love quirky js stuff like this :)

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with? It's just a matter of stepping through the execution path of that statement...

Comment: I'm surprised to. I'd expect that expression to return an int, not a string, so with the strict `===` I'd expect false.

Comment: @RGraham, Ive been stepping through. But I want to know how [Array[0]] is eventually converted to "0" -> "00" -> "10"

Comment: Oh Javascript.. You evil mistress

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has already been asked and answered before.

Comment: @Filburt, care to point us to an answer?

Comment: couldn't find it :/ but if so, please mark as duplicate and sorry.

Comment: Not exactly the same statement but the general ideal applies: *Why is ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] = '10'* http://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/205233

Comment: @AmmarCSE :   `(++[[]][+[]]) + ([+[]])`  Number plus string is string.

Comment: I have to link this: http://escape.alf.nu/ "Why people concerned with security of their web application absolutely hate the quirky JS/HTML combo" :D Pretty soon, you'll get to using constructs like this - it's actually pretty easy to write any javascript code without using any letters or numbers - at all.