# Why does ++[[]][0] return 1 instead of reporting an error?

Tags: javascript

This is valid and returns the number 1 in JavaScript:

```
++[[]][0]
```

Why doesn't it reporting an error like `++[]`?

Isn't it the same as `++[]`?

NOTE: This is a bit different than: [Why does ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] return the string “10”.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/864233)

What I mean is that why doesn't `++[[]][0]` report an error? Is `[[]][0]` a variable? If not, why doesn't it report the error like:

```
++[] // returns Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10?rq=1. While not an *exact* duplicate, it's close enough and gives you the pieces to figure your question out.

Comment: The real question is, why would you ever write this code in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

[The prefix increment operator (`++`) calls PutValue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4), and [PutValue throws a ReferenceError when the argument is not a Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2).

So in the same way that

```
var a = [];
++a; // returns 1
```

is valid because `a` is a Reference to `[]`, but `++[]` is not valid because `[]` is an array literal, not a reference.

Similarly, `[[]][0]` is a Reference to `[]`, so incrementing that Reference is again, valid.

This is also similar to

```
++1 // throws ReferenceError
var a = 1;
++a // returns 2
```