# How is alert(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]); calculated to 0?

Tags: javascript, pre-increment

How is alert(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]); calculated to 0?
What is this process called so that I can read more about this

Comment: what you try to do ? explain more

Comment: actually in jsfiddle it is 10! :0
@Bhargav... I think it is just for curiosity... I would like to know also why JS calculates here anything at all

Comment: See [JSFUCK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSFuck)

Comment: @Jaromanda X thank you. They had asked this in an interview written test and I had not idea what it was or what it was called

Comment: I don't understand why would people ask this kinda questions during interviews, are they looking for developers or brain Fxxxers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] return the string "10"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]` will actually return the string `'10'`. Let's break it down:

**Step 1: `+[]`**

This is an *unary plus* operator followed by an empty array literal. The unary plus tries to convert the value that follows it into an integer. In this case the value is an array:

```
+[]; // 0

// This is identical:
Number([]); // 0
```

The returned value is equivalent to calling `[].toString()` and then giving *that* result to `Number()`. `[].toString()` will return an empty string (`''`), and `Number('')` will return `0`.

[*Array.prototype.toString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

> The Array object overrides the toString method of Object. For Array objects, the toString method joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas.

[*Number*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

> In a non-constructor context (i.e., without the `new` operator), `Number` can be used to perform a type conversion.

So, when we change occurences of `+[]` to `0` in the source, we get:

```
++[[]][0] + [0]
```

**Step 2: `[[]][0]`**

This step is a simple array member access operation: An array with one nested (empty) array is first defined, and then that first nested array is accessed with `[0]`, which simply returns `[]`. So, if we replace this part of the expression, we get:

```
++[] + [0]
```

**Step 3: `++[]`**

The `++ <value>` operator *first* tries to convert `<value>` to a number, and then increments that number by 1. The procedure for converting the array to a number in this example occurs the same way as `+[]` was in step 1: `[]` is first converted to a string (`''` in this case, because the array is empty), and then converted to a number, which again returns `0`. Lastly, `0` is incremented by `1`, which returns `1`. So if we replace this part of the expression, we get:

```
1 + [0]
```

**Step 4: `1 + [0]`**

This is the weird part of the story. You would expect this to evaluate to the integer `1`, given the information above, but actually it will evaluate to a string `'10'`. This is because of the 2 steps in the example above for the type conversions of arrays (first to string, then to number). These 2 steps were required because the arrays were always operands of *arithmetic operators*  (i.e. math calculations). The `+` operator however can serve as both an *arithmetic `+`* operator or a *string concatenation* operator, and the latter always has precedence.

So as soon as `[0]` is converted to a string, both operands given to the `+` operator will be converted to a string, because one operand is *already* a string. If we now replace the expression with converted operands we get the final step in evaluating the expression:

```
'1' + '0'; // '10'
```

Comment: @ Jeffrey Westerkamp is there any precedence for this, I mean in general, not just for this code

Comment: If you mean _should I use this in any of my projects_, the answer is definitely no. These snippets should be considered to be just puzzles to help you understand the quirks of JS. My opinion: never, ever, use this kind of 'magic' in real-life scenarios.