# Why does [][[]] evaluate to undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, semantics, coercion

The expression `[][[]]` evaluates to `undefined` in JavaScript. My understanding of this was that the compiler sees the second set of `[...]` and interprets that to be an array subscript operator (because you can't have two arrays next to each other).

So the compiler knows that the inner expression, `[]`, must be an index, and so after evaluating it, it coerces it to a number. `Number([])` evaluates to `0`, and so we have `[][0]`, which is `undefined`.

However, `[1][[]]` does not evaluate to `1` as I would expect, but rather to `undefined` suggesting that in this case (or maybe also in the previous case), `[]` *isn't* being coerced to a number. It seems that I must use the unary `+` to force the type coercion:

```
[1][+[]] // returns 1
```

So *if* the inner `[]` in the expression `[][[]]` is not being coerced to a number, then why does that expression evaluate to `undefined`?

Comment: Similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] return the string "10"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10)

Comment: You mention: *and so after evaluating it, it coerces it to a number*, which isn't the case. Instead it tries to coerce it to a *string*, which for an empty array is just `""`. Since `[1]` has no `""` field, the result is `undefined`. You can verify that by evaluating `[1][[0]]` to get `1`

Comment: Ohh, all keys are coerced to strings. I knew that was true for `Object`s, but forgot that arrays are special `Object`s. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I'm on the fence about whether the linked question is a proper duplicate. It's certainly related, but my question is more specific. Reading the accepted answer didn't answer my question. I don't believe he called out the fact that array subscripts are coerced into strings.

Comment: [Specification](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation), [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#property_names). Related: [Are functions valid keys for javascript object properties?](/q/10858632/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faulty assumption was that the expression that evaluates to the index is coerced to a number. It is in fact coerced to string as are all object keys (except for Symbols, which stay Symbols).

Thus, `[1][[]]` turns into `[1][""]`, and since the `""` property doesn't exist on the array, we get `undefined` instead of `1`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to get data with object.property.property so objects have properties, yes true but properties dont have properties, so it makes undefined. Think like this;

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(myArray['length']);
// -> 3
console.log(myArray['length']['length']);
// -> undefined
```

And there i think there is a problem,
[]**[**[]**]** These brackets doesnt affect the code. Try to result it with some Codes;

```
let myArray = [[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3], 2, 3];
console.log(myArray[0][[0]]);
// -> [1, 2, 3]
console.log(myArray[0][0]);
// -> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm not getting data with `object.property.property`. I have one array `[]` and I'm accessing one property on it whose key is `[]`. Second, the outer `[]` brackets do affect my code. `[][]` won't compile. I need to put a key in there.