# Why console.log((!+[]+[]+![]).length) gives 9?

Tags: javascript

By what logic `js` works (!+[]+[]+![]).length returns 9? How is that possible?
As I know js has dynamic types cast but very hard to understand whats going on here

```js
console.log((!+[]+[]+![]).length);
```

Comment: [We had enough JSF explain question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10?rq=1).

Comment: You can refer full list here: http://www.jsfuck.com/

Comment: You'd be a lot closer to answering your own question if you tried logging `!+[]+[]+![]`

Comment: ...and then logging `!+[]`, then `!+[]+[]` ...

Comment: (some users keep upvoting "fun" questions. Some "good" one are not upvoted. Not a good thing. **Your upvotes have a big effect, please use them carefully**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we have to understand !+[]+[]+![]:

```
!+[] = !0 = true   
true+[] = "true"
![] = false
"true"+false = "truefalse"
```

so length of `!+[]+[]+![]` is length of "truefalse" so it's 9

Answer (score 5):

First: +[]

+[] is casting the array to a string, then a number. [] becomes "" and then becomes 0.
+[123] is +"123", so it's 123
+[1,2] is +"1,2", this is not a number, so it's NaN

!+[] is !0 (not zero), so it's the boolean true

Second: true + []

Convert both to string, so "true" + "" is "true"

Third: ![]

![] is the boolean false, because an object/array is always thruty.

Fourth: "true" + false

Convert boolean false to a string, so "true" + "false" is "truefalse"

"truefalse".length is 9