# understanding Javascript weird not operator and empty arrays expression

Tags: javascript

I was preparing for an exam and found this (!+[]+[]+![])  expression and I'm wondering why it is equal to "truefalse" in javascript ?

Comment: it's due to type coercion, unary +, and boolean operations

Comment: Empty array toString gives `""`, `+""` gives `0`,  `!0` gives `true` etc...

Comment: Related: [Why does ++\[\[\]\]\[+\[\]\]+\[+\[\]\] return the string "10"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/4642212). When trying to figure this out yourself, where exactly was the difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operators used here are:

- `!`, negation, [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) 17
- `+`, unary +, precedence 17
- `+`, addition, precedence 14

Spacing it out according to operator precedence:

```
(!+[] + [] + ![])
```

Evaluate the 3 expressions, then use addition on the three:

`!+[]`: unary `+` first coerces the empty array to a number. Arrays, when turned into primitives, have `.join(',')` called on them. Here, with no elements, the empty string is the result, and the empty string, when turned into a number, is 0, since it's falsey. Then `!` inverts that and turns it into a boolean, making it `true`.

```
(true + [] + ![])
```

`+` operates left-to-right. As said before, when the empty array is coerced to a primitive, it becomes the empty string. So `true + []` results in `true + ''`, resulting in the string `'true'`.

```
('true' + ![])
```

Arrays are truthy. Invert the truthyness of that with `!`, and you get `false`:

```
('true' + false)
```

With `+`, when either side is not numeric, both sides get coerced to strings. The result is `'truefalse'`.

Comment: great answer, there's a lot of important basics here.  i didn't even know you could concat a boolean to get the string "true".