# How/why does this javascript code print 'fun'?

Tags: javascript

```
alert(
    (![]+[])[[]-[]]+
    (([]+[])+([][[]]))[[]-[]]+
    (([]+[])+([][[]]))[!![]-[]]
);
```

Heres' the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leeny/6VugZ/

How exactly is this cryptic piece of code working?

Comment: Because strings can be indexed.

Comment: Break it down in the console. It's awesome.

Comment: Ugh; why is this getting upvotes? All you need to do, if you can't figure it out by looking at it, is try one small piece at a time. It's a little depressing.

Comment: The same way these work: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4170978/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/218196.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        vvvvvvv [0]
(![]+[])[[]-[]]                            = "false"[0]
^^^^^^^^ "false"

                  vvvvvvv again [0]
(([]+[])+([][[]]))[[]-[]]                  = "undefined"[0]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ "undefined"

                  vvvvvvvvv this time [1]
(([]+[])+([][[]]))[!![]-[]]                = "undefined"[1]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ again "undefined"
```

Thus you get `"f"+"u"+"n" === "fun"`.

### Further explanation

#### `"false"`

`![]` is `false`. `+[]` simply acts as a transformation into a string. Thus we gain the string `"false"`.

#### `"undefined"`

One of the operands needs to be a string. This is being done by `[]+[]`. The actual `undefined` is created in the right hand side: `[][[]]` === `[][0]`, the first entry of an empty array is `undefined`.

Comment: As a side note, `(([]+[])+([][[]]))` seems like overkill to me, `([]+[][[]])` appears to suffice.

Comment: @Neil: There are other overkills too: `[[]-[]] === [+[]]`. I believe `(![]+[])[+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+[]]+([]+[][[]])[+!![]]` is the shortest sequence which creates the same result.