# Javascript's Arrays and Objects returning String

Tags: javascript

I was reading these [slides](https://speakerdeck.com/dherman/es6-deep-dive?slide=64) and I found the following javascript line:

```
 ({} + [])[!![] + !![] + !![]] + (![] + [])[!![] + !![] + !![]]
```

If you execute this line at the console, **it will return "js".**
  Altering the code makes the line return different letters. I could almost return my name(missing "n"):

```
({} + [])[!![] + !![] + !![]] + (![] + {})[!![] + !![] + !![] + !![]] + (![] + {})[![] + !![] ]
```

**Why this happens? How this works?** The slides didn't give much information about it.

Comment: Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7202157/218196, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4170978/218196

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find these answers because I had no keyword as reference to look for.

Comment: I simply searched for `[javascript] "{} + []"` and `[javascript] "!![]"` ;) (but I knew that there are similar questions, so it was easy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `{} + []` : When the `+` has operands other than numbers, it calls `toString` on both operands and concatenates their values. `{}.toString()` returns `[object Object]` and `[].toString()` returns the contents of the array which is simply an empty string as the array holds nothing:

  ```
   ("[object Object]" + "")[!![] + !![] + !![]] + (![] + [])[!![] + !![] + !![]]

   ==>

   "[object Object]"[!![] + !![] + !![]] + (![] + [])[!![] + !![] + !![]]
  ```
- When `[]` is converted to a boolean, it returns true. A logical `!!` returns true if its operand doesn't compare to `undefined`, `null`, `0`, or an empty string `""`. Therefore `!![]` returns true.

  When arithmetic is done on boolean values, integral promotion is performed. The values `true` and `false` are converted to `1` and `0` respectively:

  ```
  "[object Object]"[true + true + true] + (![] + [])[true + true + true]

  ==>

  "[object Object]"[1 + 1 + 1] + (![] + [])[1 + 1 + 1]

  ==>

  "[object Object]"[3] + (![] + [])[3]
  ```
- The subscript operator `[n]` obtains the `(n + 1)-th` member of an array-like structure (because arrays are 0-indexed). The first `[3]` obtains the 4th character of the string with is `"j"`:

  ```
  "j" + (![] + [])[3]
  ```
- `![]` returns false (because `[]` is truthy) and `[]` returns an empty string:

  ```
  "j" + (false + "")[3]

  ==>

  "j" + "false"[3]
  ```
- The 4th character in `"false"` is "s" (arrays are 0-indexed). So this resolves to:

  ```
  "j" + "s"

  ==> "js"
  ```

Comment: Good explanation. At the end, it is not so complicated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely there are two things going on, one is addition of an empty object and an array, and the other is an indexer.

In JS, `{} + []` returns 0

`({} + [])` returns "[object Object]"

`[] + {}` returns "[object Object]"

`![] + {}` returns "false[object Object]"

`(![] + [])` returns "false"

In addition, since everything is type-convertible, `true+true` = 2 (true being equivalent to 1).  `!![]` will return `true` (the boolean) so `!![] + !![] + ![]` is the same as doing `true + true + true` which will equal 3.

So for this, you're evaluating things that come out as strings, then indexing over those strings to get the individual characters.  You have anything in the words "false" and "Object" to choose from.