# Obfuscated code without function calls

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I've seen examples of code that uses only operators and `""` to perform complex string operations. Basically, the idea was that something like `((+"+")+"")[+""]` gives you a letter `N`, etc. I forgot where I found it,  and I'm having no luck finding proper google keywords. Does anyone have a link at hand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically there are two main concepts used here:

1. making a `Number` out of string, i.e. `Number(str)`, which shortcut is `+str`;
2. stringifying numeric values, i.e. `String(n)`, which shortcut is `n+""`.

Hence, if we look at the expression thoroughly, we'll see:

```
+"+"     === NaN
NaN + "" === "NaN"
+""      === 0
"NaN"[0] === "N"
```

There are a lot of things you can do in JavaScript in the same way. One funny example is provided in the following question: [What are JavaScript's builtin strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15978204/1249581)

Comment: +1 Following the same two concepts, there is a crappy IE 6-7-8 detection script that goes like that : `if(!+"\v1")`, Javascript interpreter will always try to do something before giving up, which can be a mess on other browsers unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was somewhere on SO. Thanks a lot!