# Jquery loop form to check for all empty fields then execute a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to loop form to check for empty field and then execute and function. I'm currently using something like this below that I found on this website but what is happening that the each loop check 1 field and see 1 that not empty and still execute else function. I think I need to check all at once then execute next function. How could I achieve this?

```
if($('.enter-info--ownerInfo .req').val() != "") {
   alert("Empty Fields!!")
    } else {
    run this function
    }
```

Thanks...

Comment: You need to check each field, you can't do this with a single selector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [filtering](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), it is easy:

```
var anyFieldIsEmpty = $("form :input").filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
    }).length > 0;

if (anyFieldIsEmpty) {
    // empty fields
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lz9nY/

Comment: Any reason to use length instead of: $.trim(this.value) === "" ?

Comment: It could probably even be `return !$.trim(this.value);`

Comment: @Ian It couldn't be that. Remember about "0".

Comment: @roasted Just because I like `length` property, nothing more `;)`

Comment: @VisioN  Ok, seems fair ;)

Comment: @VisioN Not true. Try it :) `"0"` is truthy - the only falsey string is `""`. It's different when **comparing to** a boolean

Comment: @VisioN As soon as you said no, I got really confused, so I had to go try it and make sure :)

Comment: @Ian You also puzzled me with that `:)` These falsy-tricks are always mixed up in my head.

Comment: Thanks VisioN just what I been looking for.

Comment: @VisioN I know, me too! Sometimes it's better to be explicit and easier to read - you probably have less problems/confusion, and it gets the same job done

Comment: @Ian Yup! That's why I haven't edited the answer -- it should be easier for the OP to get the idea. But regarding `x === ""`, I don't know why, but for me `x.length === 0` looks very much better `:)`

Comment: @VisioN Oh absolutely, I didn't intend for you to swap it in your answer; keeping it in the comments is right :)

Comment: @Ian Haha! Regarding these JS-tricks, I just remembered that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16036784/1249581). After all we should be professors here, but still are mixing the things `:)`

Comment: @VisioN Oh wow! I didn't know anyone ever answered it! I swear the last time I saw that, we were still going back and forth in the comments, and I thought there would be no way. Thanks for bringing that up, in any case!

Comment: @Ian I have found that question absolutely accidentally while searching for something really different. Imagine my surprise when I read the question about the snippet from my profile! I just decided to give a small clarification, which finally brought us to several new JS obfuscators `:D`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.enter-info--ownerInfo .req').each(function() {

  if ($(this).val() == "")
  {
     alert("empty field : " + $(this).attr('id'));
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by selecting all your fields:

```
var fields = $('.enter-info--ownerInfo .req')
```

Then filter them down to the ones with an empty value:

```
fields.filter(function() {
    return this.value === '';
});
```

Then check the `length` property of the resulting object. If it's equal to `0` then all fields have a value, otherwise you execute your function.

```
if(fields.length === 0) {
    // no empty fields
}
else {
    // empty fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and flag:

```
var valid = true;
$('.req').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        valid = false;
        return false;
    }
});

if (valid) {
    // all fields are valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to reduce the elements to those matching your criteria:

```
if $('.enter-info--ownerInfo .req').filter(function () {
  return $.trim($(this).val()) == ""
}).length > 0) {
  alert("One or more fields are empty")
} else {
  // run this function
}
```