# Why and how does ([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]] evaluate to the letter "i"?

Tags: javascript, types, obfuscation, ecmascript-5

While reading [this article posted on dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/dynamic-languages-have-jumped) I found a snippet of JavaScript originally [posted on Twitter by Marcus Lagergren](https://twitter.com/lagergren/statuses/337484475204255744).

The following code apparently prints the string `"fail"`

```
(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]];
```

This involves implicit type casting and I'm trying to understand how exactly this line is interpreted.

I've isolated each character

- `(![]+[])[+[]]` prints `"f"`
- `(![]+[])[+!+[]]` prints `"a"`
- `([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]` prints `"i"`
- `(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]` prints `"l"`

I've also managed to break down the expressions returning each letter apart from `"i"`

### letter `"f"`

`![]` an empty array is an Object, which according to [ECMAScript documentation, point 9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) evaluates to `true` when converted to a `boolean` so this is `false`

`false+[]` as per [Point 11.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) both arguments of the binary `+` operator get converted to String, therefore we get `"false"+""`, which evaluates `"false"`

`+[]` a unary plus operator causes a `ToNumber` conversion followed by a `ToPrimitive` conversion if the argument is an `Object`. The result of such conversion is determined by calling the `[[DefaultValue]]` internal method of the object. In case of an empty array, it defaults to `0`.
(ECMAScript Documentation, sections: [11.4.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6), [9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3), [9.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.1) )

`"false"[0]` we're accessing the character at index `0`, hence the `"f"`

### letter `"a"`

Same story, the only difference here are additional conversions in the part in square brackets (which evaluates to a number to point at another character in the string `"false"`), triggered by the use of unary `+` and `!` operators.

`+[]` evaluates to `0`, as explained above.

`!0` evaluates to `true` as defined in [Section 9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) and [Section 11.4.9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9). First, `0` is converted to a boolean `false` and then the operator inverts the value.

`+true` again, the unary plus triggers a `ToNumber` conversion, which returns a `1` for binary `true`
([Section 11.4.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) and [9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3))

`"false"[1]` returns the second character in the string, which is `"a"`

### letter "l"

`!+[]` evaluates to `true` as explained above

`true+true` using the binary `+` on primitives triggers a `ToNumber` conversion. In case of true, its result is `1` and `1+1` equals `2`

`"false"[2]` - self explanatory

### letter `"i"`

What leaves me stumped is the letter `"i"`. I can see that the second part (in square brackets) evaluates to the string `"10"` and that the first part (in parentheses) returns `"falseundefined"` but **I can't make heads or tails of how this is happening. Could someone explain it step by step?** Especially the magic that happens with square brackets? (arrays and array access)

***If possible, I'd like each step to contain a link to the underlying ECMAScript rules.***

What I find the most cryptic is this part: `[][[]]`

Comment: rel http://stackoverflow.com/q/15978204/989121

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your cryptic part isn't all that cryptic if you rewrite it a little:

```
[]['']
```

`[]` will be coerced into a string because it isn't an integer, so you're looking for a property of `[]` with the name `''` (an empty string). You'll just get `undefined`, as there is no property with that name.

As for the actual letter, break the expression up into the two main components:

- The string `([![]]+[][[]])`:

  - `[![]]` is `[false]`.
  - `[][[]]` is `undefined`.
  - Add them together and you get **`"falseundefined"`.**
- And the index: `[+!+[]+[+[]]]`. Some whitespace and parentheses will make the operations much clearer: `[+(!(+[])) + [+[]]]`:

  - `[+[]]` is **`[0]`**.
  - `+[]` coerces `[]` to an integer, so you get `0`.
  - `!+[]` coerces `0` to a boolean and negates it, so you get `true`.
  - `+!+[]` coerces `true` to an integer, so you get **`1`**.
  - Add them together, and you get `["10"]`.

When using a string to access the properties of the array and the string happens to be an element of the array, the string is coerced into an integer and you get back the actual element of the array:

```
> [1, 2, 3]["0"]
1
> [1, 2, 3]["1"]
2
```

So your final result is:

```
> "falseundefined"["10"]
"i"
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9033306/464744) for an explanation of the `[false] + undefined` part.

Answer (score 2):

`([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]` has two parts :

`([![]]+[][[]])` and the other which you found yourself.

`![]` returns `false`. Then we use `[...]` to get the `.toString()` behavior of `+`.
(`[]+[]` is the same as `[].toString()+[].toString()`)
the `[][[]]` is undefined because we're trying to access the index `[]` (or `[].toString()`, which is `''`) of `[]` which is undefined.