# What is the result of sum of empty object and empty array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
[] + {} = "[object Object]"
{} + [] = 0
[] + [] = ""
{} + {} = NaN
```

Who can explain me, why these operations give totally unexpected results?
How does operator overloading is set for "+" in such kind of situations?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014770/why-and-how-does-evaluate-to-the-letter-i

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7124907