# Why does the concat function return an array with window in it?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap my head around this javascript snippet:

```
(_=[].concat)()[0]
```

It returns window, but why?

Comment: If you are interested in different options of obfuscation in JavaScript you may also have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16036784/1249581.

Comment: @VisioN universal obfuscating tool... awesome stuff.. :D

Answer (score 1):

After breaking it down into its components it's easier to understand what's going on.

You can basically rewrite this snippet as:

```
Array.prototype.concat.call(this)[0]
```

When you call a function, it gets its `this` context from the object before the `.`, so the function call `object.toString()` will have its `this` reference set to `object`. However, when a function doesn't have a containing object, its context will default to the global scope, meaning `window` in browsers. `concat` will normally use the existing array context it is called on to use as the base array to concatenate on to, but in this case `window` is the context, so it is cast into an array and then concat is applied to it, but since nothing is provided to be concatenated, it just returns an array with the context, which is window.