# How does this code alert "n"?

Tags: javascript

The following code alerts "n".  How does this code work?

```
alert(([]+[][1])[[[+!-[]][0]]])
```

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15978204/1249581.

Comment: Have a look here : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8263/javascript-written-only-with-brackets

Comment: Wait, "unclear what you're asking"? Whats unclear?

Comment: Agreed; there may be good reasons to close this (probably a duplicate) but it's way above the bar for clarity around here.

Comment: Im really not going to interprete this expression but, might be you are trying to print the first letter of a string representing a non existen numeric expression resultin in NaN and the first letter is N

Comment: http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Comment: @nicael We require that questions have a clear problem statement to be useful to future visitors; your initial title and body was not clear nor useful to future visitors.

Comment: @nicael work through the subexpressions in your browser console. You'll understand it better if you do that anyway. Also note that there are no useful JavaScript coding skills to be learned from this, but it may help recognize weird buggy behavior caused by code that *accidentally* stumbles into such trickery.

Comment: There is no way to reopen it, @Pointy?

Comment: @nicael I voted to reopen, as did three others. Really, just start with seeing what `([]+[][1])` looks like in your browser console.

Comment: @VisioN: yea, that's a better close vote :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it alerts `([]+[][1])[[[+!-[]][0]]]`.

Let's break that up:

```
    -[]      // -0   (Apparently -`array` == -0)
   !-[]      // true (Boolean NOT on -1 == true)
  +!-[]      //  1   (+ casts `true` to a number (1))
 [+!-[]]     // [1]  (add array brackets) (wow that's cheap)
 [+!-[]][0]  //  1   (get 1st element of the array) 
[[+!-[]][0]] // [1]  (add array brackets)

    []       // []          (Empty array)
    [][1]    // "undefined" (empty string @ 1 == undefined)
 []+[][1]    // ""          (undefined + array == undefined)
([]+[][1])   // "undefined"

"undefined"[[1]]         // "n" (Get the character at zero-indexed position `1`)
([]+[][1])[[[+!-[]][0]]] // "n"
```

The extra square brackets don't matter much, when accessing an array:

```
[1][[[[[[0]]]]]] === [1][0] === [1]["0"] === 1;
```

This is because, behind the scenes, the supplied index is converted to a string:

```
[[[[[0]]]]].toString() === "0";
```

Comment: THX, Cerbus. Now its clear.

Comment: Actually the first part of expression is not interperted in this way.

Here []+[][1] first is evaluated the second empty brackets.
[] - you get an empty array.
[][1] - indexing on the empty array returns you undefined.
[] + [][1] - casts the empty array to empty string and empty string plus undefined gives you "undefined" as as string.

The other part is correct. You can try to add parentheses on different places to check the precedence.

Comment: Oh, yea, you're right! I did check my code in the console, though, `[]+[]` does in fact equal `""`, and `""[1] == undefined`, but that's not what's happening, indeed. Fixed my answer.