# Why is (([]===[])+/-/)[1] = 'a' and (1+{})[(1<<1)+1] = 'b' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Recently I came across an interesting website that illustrates a Javascript Obfuscator: http://bl.ocks.org/jasonsperske/5400283

For example, `(([]===[])+/-/)[1]` gives `a` and `(1+{})[(1<<1)+1]` gives `b`.

I have tried hard to understand the evaluation sequence of these obfuscated result but was in vain.

Taking `(1+{})[(1<<1)+1]` as an example, I understand that `<<` is the bitwise shift operator and will return 2, so the expression becomes `(1+{})[3]`. But then I cannot understand what does it mean by `1+{}` and `[3]`.

Google isn't really helpful to this problem as search engines don't like the brackets or slashes very much, so in case there are duplicate questions I'm sorry about that.

Comment: The expression result is stringified, the indexes are used as charAt function for Strings.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978204/what-are-javascripts-builtin-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just obfuscation tricks.

for example :

`[]===[]` ===> `false`

and

`([]===[])+/-/` ===> `"false/-/"`   ( You could test it in the console by yourself)

So what is `(([]===[])+/-/)[1]` ? ( second char)

That's right :'a'

You *may* want to look at this also :

[image]

Comment: But why `[]===[]` will give false? Aren't they identical null arrays?

Comment: @Pingu You compare **references**. a new blank array has different address than another new blank array.

Answer (score 3):

`1+{}`'s result is a string `"1[object Object]"`, `(1+{})[3]` is to get the char of index 3 which is `b`.

The first example:

`[]===[]`
Comparing two different objects with `===`, so the result is `false`, whose toString result is `"false"`.

`/-/` is a regex object, whose toString result is `"/-/"`

When you do `false + /-/`, which will concat using the result of `.toString()`, so the result will be `"false/-/"`, and the second char is `a`.

Answer (score 3):

You could go step by step:

```
(([]===[]))
```

is simply `false`. Converted into a string `"false/-/"`and indexed by `[1]` gives you the `a` of the string "false".

The same goes for `(1+{})` which results in the string `"1[object Object]"`.
And 1<<1+1 is another way of writing `3` so this results in `"1[object Object]"[3]`, which is simply `b`.