# Why does [] + [] return an empty string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lately i have been experimenting with node.js and I found out that javascript has some syntactic logic that I could not wrap my head around. This is an example I do not understand and I was wondering whether this is just a random javascript fact or if there is any logic to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The plus sign is either arithmetic plus or string concatenation. The empty arrays are converted to empty strings in the case of `[] + []`.

The Array's [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method will return one string that is the comma separated list of all of the array's elements.

From the the MDN reference above:

> JavaScript calls the toString method automatically when an array is to be represented as a text value or when an array is referred to in a string concatenation.

The same idea of automatic type conversion is why `true + true === 2`, and type conversion is the basis of many tricky JavaScript quizzes like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works/4171028).

Comment: +1 for essentially the correct answer. Properly speaking, the arrays are _converted_ to strings (via a call to `toPrimitive()`), not cast. See the [EcmaScript spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1)

Comment: @TedHopp - Thanks for the catch. Expanded the answer a little.

Answer (score 3):

For Non primitive types like arrays, for applying addition, it has to be converted to primitive, ToPrimitive, would call toString() for non primitive types. So, in this case [] becomes "", and hence "", as the result.