# Language made only of brackets, plus and exclamation marks

Tags: programming-languages

A colleague of mine sent me a snippet of code made only of brackets ()[]{}, plus signs and exclamation marks.

```
[][(![]+[])[!+[]+!![]+!![]]+([]+{})[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+!![]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]]
```

and it goes on like this..

This vaguely reminds me of [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), but I couldn't find any esoteric language written like this.

Could you help me understand what language is it?

Comment: run it through your JavaScript Console

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is hardly a constructive programming problem related question.

Comment: @deceze if this is off-topic, I am willing to rephrase, move or delete the question. I posted here because I couldn't find an answer via google and I think this may happen to other people.

Comment: Thanks, @remyabel and Gordon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(!\[\]+\[\])\[+\[\]\]... Explain why this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This link explains it pretty well how this kind of javascript code works:
http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Here is a short summary:
The main trick that makes this work is typecasting:
`[]` is an empty array
`+[] === 0` casts this empty array to a number, namely zero
`!+[] === true` then casts the zero to false and negates it to true
`!+[]+!+[] === 2` is basically adding true+true. so the trues are casted to 1 and then added. This way you can get arbitrary numbers.

But numbers are not enough to program, right?
`[]+{} === "[object Object]"` we can get strings by adding an empty object (`{}`) to arbitrary things like for example an empty array (`[]`).
`([]+{})[+!+[]] === "o"` we can then get the second character of the string by doing an array access on that string (`"abc"[1] == "b"`).

But we are still limited to that 10 characters present in that string. We can expand that by converting other things to string like:
`"undefined" === [][+[]]+[]` (accessing an undefined index of an array), 
`"NaN" === +{}+[]` (cast object to number), 
`"true" === !![]+[]`,
`"false" === ![]+[]`

Then you still dont have arbitrary characters, but from here there are several ways to get them. For example if you are targeting browsers you can use the `btoa` function (`btoa` takes a string as input and returns the base64 encoded version of it) to get arbitrary ASCII characters.

The final step is then to execute our generated string:
`[]["sort"]["constructor"]("OUR_CODE")()`
We first get the the sort function which every array has as a property. Then we access the constructor of the sort function, which is the `Function` function. It can be used to construct arbitrary anonymous functions and takes a string with code as input. Finally we call our newly created function with ()

Comment: It would be nice if the link didn't point to a 404 page.

Comment: @user258081 https://web.archive.org/web/20220121095034/http://patriciopalladino.com/blog/2012/08/09/non-alphanumeric-javascript.html

Answer (score 2):

It's called JSFuck. Take a look at this links below.

JSFuck Encoder: http://www.jsfuck.com/

Decode JSFuck: [How to decode a JSFuck script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862135/how-to-decode-a-jsfuck-script)
https://enkhee-osiris.github.io/Decoder-JSFuck/

Comment: links can be temporary can you paste your answer in this section