# How to decode a JSFuck script?

Tags: javascript, jsfuck

I have this code in JavaScript:

```
[(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]
```

In the console, it will return

```
Array [ "filter" ]
```

And how can I decode a lot of text that’s similar to the text above? E.g.:

```
[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+
([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
([][[]]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+([][[]]+[])[+[]]+([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+
(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+
(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+
([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+
(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]
```

I want to see the plain script.

Comment: [Here you go.](http://www.jsfuck.com/)

Comment: This should not have been downvoted. Pretty interesting stuff.

Comment: @MikeC what do you think a more constructive title would be? I think this Q&A could be quite helpful. What are people likely to google for this? "Decoding Atomic JavaScript", other thoughts?

Comment: @Madness It’s still the same title, I just removed the tag from the title.

Comment: @Madness I don't think this question is suitable for Stack Overflow. As was mentioned elsewhere, JSFuck requires understanding type coercion, native types strings, and more in JS. That's a pretty broad field of knowledge.

Comment: @Madness Maybe something with “obfuscated JavaScript”, “block-like JS code”, “unreadable JS”, the fact that the code only consists of six symbols…

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28714/convert-jsfuck-to-normal-js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have seen many decoding attempts around, but none that work reliably. The easiest way I have found to decode Non Alphanumeric Javascript is with Chrome.

Open Chrome > Go to jsfuck.com > paste the code you would like to decode in the window > hit Run This.

Then open the Console, in the case of your [specific code from PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/HZrmFcUQ) there will be an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

To the right of the error, click the line number link, and the code will be revealed. The result is:

```
(function(){
    window.false=document.getElementById('sc').innerHTML;
})
```

Which explains why you get the error trying to just decode it using JSFuck itself. There is no element with the id `sc` on their site.

Comment: You can paste it in that box on their website, you will likely need to uncheck `Eval Source`.

Comment: You can also decode it by hand once you understand how JS type coercion works.

Comment: I can also do long division by hand.

Comment: @Madness I want to see native code too... If I decode "a" with checked Excutable code and decode it with unchecked Excutable code I get: `(![]+[+!![]]+![]+![].........`

Comment: I want to decode this script: http://pastebin.com/HZrmFcUQ (note: last char is **;** ) Can I get plain script? I don't want to decode it by hand...

Comment: I put the output you were looking for above. Its a couple steps, I wouldn't call it by hand.

Comment: You were already trying to decode with JSFuck, now all you need to do after you run it there is to check the console's error, that is where the raw code output is. (And in Chrome)

Comment: Why don't you run the script (in an isolated env) and then, reimplment it? Use Chrome's dev tools to see what the code is doing.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this website to decode jsfuck:
http://codertab.com/jsunfuck

*UPDATED*
I extracted the decode javascript from the URL above, this is how the decode process work: (javascript)

s = source.slice(0, source.length - 2);
txtResult = eval(s);

Hope it help!

Comment: Hello @Tubekeeper, Welcome to SO, please provide and explanation to your answer, in that way it will be more likely to get up-voted.

Comment: It doesn't really decode it then, it interprets it using eval x'] But i probably misunderstood the question since i was thinking it would transpile it back to code

Comment: Sadly, both the site you suggested and the one suggested in the other answer do not give you access to the original raw code however.

Answer (score 2):

```
    let elem = yourJSFuck
function decode(elem) {
    return (/\n(.+)/.exec(eval(elem.replace(/\s+/, "").slice(0, -2)))[1]);
}

console.log(decode(elem))
```

This should work, the source is from [this page](https://enkhee-osiris.github.io/Decoder-JSFuck/)

Comment: Sadly, both the site you suggested and the one suggested in the other answer do not give you access to the original raw code however.