# Why does this print out 10?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(++[[]][+[]]+[+[]]);
```

Why in the world does this print out 10 and not something else...? Its been driving me crazy for too long. I found this while reading the following article:

http://tutorialzine.com/2013/12/the-10-weirdest-programming-languages/

Perhaps someone can provide a definitive solution. I look forward to your swift responses everyone.

Comment: Duplicate, duplicate.. an exact match too, found by searching the site for `"++[]"` (the stackoverflow internal search supports finding symbols when quotes are used).

Comment: Is this an actual problem?

Comment: Stackoverflow links at bottom of that page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-is-10, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only six different characters to write and execute any JS code. For example here are some representations to JS constructs

```
false       =>  ![]
true        =>  !![]
undefined   =>  [][[]]
NaN         =>  +[![]]
0           =>  +[]
1           =>  +!+[]
2           =>  !+[]+!+[]
10          =>  [+!+[]]+[+[]]
Array       =>  []
Number      =>  +[]
String      =>  []+[]
Boolean     =>  ![]
Function    =>  []["filter"]
eval        =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]( CODE )()
window      =>  []["filter"]["constructor"]("return this")()
```

Proof at [JS F*ck](http://www.jsfuck.com/) and detail at [Why does ++[[]][+[]]+[+[]] return the string "10"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-is-10)