# Array concatenation evaluating to string "test"

Tags: javascript

Can any body breakdown why this expression evaluates to "test"

```js
console.log((!+[]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!+[]+[])[+[]])
```

Comment: Why not experiment by seeing what each part does?

Comment: Related https://github.com/aemkei/jsfuck

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170978/explain-why-this-works) thread.